# Figuring out number of days between two datetimes

Tags: datetime, activerecord

I have datetime field `t.datetime :schedule_time` defined in my activerecord schema. How can I get the number of days between `Time.now` and `Item.schedule_time`?

Doing `(Time.now - Item.schedule_time).to_i` returns something in the thousands range, which is not right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby, Rails and difference between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996183/ruby-rails-and-difference-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Time.now - Item.schedule_time` gives the number of seconds passed. Just divide that by number of seconds in a day and I'll have the days passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`distance_of_time_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words). It will do exactly what you need.